# Android Studio won´t show any errors

Tags: android-studio

Suddenly Android Studio stopped showing inline errors. Even when there´s a missing import. I have tried the following:

1- Clean Project

2- Rebuild project

3- Invalidate cache and restart

4- Check if the power save mode is on

5- Resync the Gradle

6- Delete the .gradle and .idea folder

7- Delete the .iml and .idea folder

8- Reinstall Android Studio

I don´t know what else I could try.
Need some help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had installed the Android ButterKnife Zelezny plugin. Besides that it didn´t work at all, it somehow disabled the inline errors functionality in Android Studio.